# What is the physical meaning of adiabatically varying the wavevector $k$ as a parameter to calculate the Chern number for topological effects?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topological-insulators, topological-phase, berry-pancharatnam-phase

Could it mean something like applying a weak electric field and perturbing the band structure? Or some other weak perturbation? Or is that the wrong idea?

Comment: I don't think it's useful to think about it as a physical process.

Comment: Why not @jahan?

Comment: Because k is not an observable quantity. There is no physical way to start an electron in a certain k state and then vary it. The berry curvature is a mathematical object, it doesn't directly describe physical processes.

Comment: Even interpreting the berry connection in the Brillouin zone as an adiabatic phase is not really useful. There's no associated adiabatic process that gives you this phase. We call it an adiabatic phase because it LOOKS like the phase you would get if you COULD vary k adiabatically, but the actual use of the berry connection has nothing to do with adiabatically varying k.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this exactly answers your question but I believe this relates to the Berry phase (and subsequent Berry curvature) that arises in a cyclic adiabatic evolution. The existence of such a Berry phase in the system gives rise to a possible non-zero Chern number, which indicates a non-trival nature to your system under study.

You can also look into how this in linked to the quantum Hall effect

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm asking for the physical interpretation of this process; i.e., what does it mean to adiabatically vary k?

Comment: Rather than type most of this here, the discussion in regards to Berry phase here is a very interesting and informative discussion in the area. https://www.researchgate.net/post/What-is-the-physical-significance-of-Berry-Phase-in-Topological-Insulators

Answer (score 0):

It does have a physical meaning as adiabatically inserting a magnetic flux through the large cycles of the torus. I'll illustrate with a one-dimensional example. Suppose you have fermions hopping on a ring of $N$ sites. Usually we impose periodic boundary condition $c_{N+1}=c_1$ ($c$ is the annihilation operator), and the lattice momenta must satisfy $e^{ikN}=1$. However, we may also consider threading a magnetic flux $\phi$ through the ring, which changes the boundary condition to $c_{N+1}=e^{i\phi}c_1$. In that case, the quantization condition for momentum becomes $e^{ikN}=e^{i\phi}$. As one varies $\phi$, the momentum $k$ becomes $k+\frac{\phi}{N}$, until when $\phi$ hits $2\pi$ and $k$ is shifted to $k+\frac{2\pi}{N}$, which is the next lattice momentum for the original periodic boundary condition. The generalization to 2D is straightforward, and the usual expression of the Chern number as an integral over the Brillouin zone can be re-cast into an integral over twisted boundary conditions. This is how Chern number is defined for a general interacting many-body system. The original reference is [Phys. Rev. B **31**, 3372 (1985)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.31.3372).